# How to extract a local .repo folder into files if the remote branch doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: git, repo

I have an old downloaded Android source code .repo folder but the remote on Github doesn't exist anymore.
The .repo folder is about 50GB.
Is there a way to extract it into source code files using the current versions of the files without trying to connect to the remote server which doesn't exist anymore?
The only way I know to extract files is to use 'repo sync' but it can't work if there are no remote repositories it can connect to.

With git it was easy, a local .git folder with no remote repository could be extracted with 'git reset --hard'

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
repo sync --local-only
```

Here is the documentation extract (`repo sync -h`):

```
-l, --local-only      only update working tree, don't fetch
```